# How to implement Click event in QGraphicsWidget?

Tags: qt

i used QT Example : appchooser . i plan to implement the Toolbar with that. i modified it's working fine.

i have problem to catch the click event. i tried but i didn't get the solution. please help me to fix the problem.

for clicking the item i need to call the `ItemClicked()` method

the project source code. 
http://www.4shared.com/file/Xutwi3DR/test4anime.html

Please help to find the solution..

Answer (score 2):

You must subclass it since `virtual void grabMouseEvent ( QEvent * event )` (in fact all mouse events) is(are) protected and there are no `signals` for click events for this widget.

```
class MyGraphicsWidget : public QGraphicsWidget{

Q_OBJECT

//Implement the constructors as you wish, if you need help with this check a Qt tutorial out.

  //to get the mouse events implement the needed functions
  //there are many others so just check the docs [1]
  virtual void mouseReleaseEvent ( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event ){
    //do whatever you need here. Emit SIGNALS, show menus, etc
  }
};
```

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qgraphicswidget-members.html [1]